# Taking the expectation out of the inner product

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, expectation, inner-products

Suppose that $X$ is a zero mean random element with values in a separable Hilbert space $\mathbb H$ such that $\operatorname E\|X\|^2<\infty$. The covariance operator $C:\mathbb H\to\mathbb H$ of $X$ is defined as $C(f)=\operatorname E[\langle X,f\rangle X]$ for each $f\in\mathbb H$. I would like to show that
$$
\langle C(f),f\rangle=\operatorname E|\langle X,f\rangle|^2
$$
for each $f\in\mathbb H$. I would like to proceed in the following way
$$
\langle C(f),f\rangle=\langle \operatorname E[\langle X,f\rangle X],f\rangle=\operatorname E\langle \langle X,f\rangle X,f\rangle=\operatorname E[\langle X,f\rangle\langle  X,f\rangle]=\operatorname E|\langle X,f\rangle|^2.
$$
However, I do not know how I can justify taking the expectation out of the inner product. If I investigate a particular Hilbert space, for example, $L^2([0,1],\mathbb R)$, then I can use Fubini's theorem to justify the interchange of the order of integration, but how can I do that in the general case? Is it possible to justify taking the expectation out of the inner product in the general case?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, but not a complete answer by any means.

Additionally, I don't know the answer to this question, but I have some suggestions that you could perhaps consider.

1. The covariance is well-defined on the Hilbert space, so this may help with applications of Fubini/Tonelli.
2. You have a *separable* Hilbert space, so taking some (countable) basis $f_1, f_2, ...$ might not be a bad shout. Maybe point 1. can be used to take this infinite sum out in some way, cancelling cross-terms. This may help as you need only consider certain $f$.
3. Moreover, you may consider $X = X^+ - X^-$ in the usual way, and consider just non-negative $f$ similarly. Of course, while $\Bbb{E}(X) = 0$, you don't necessarily have $\Bbb{E}(X^{\pm}) = 0$.

Anyway, I hope that these points may be of some help to you. Sorry that I can't be of more help!